# Is it standard behaviour for cd to automatically choose when given an incomplete directory name?

Tags: bash, cd-command, autocorrection

I have three folders called `ProjectA`, `ProjectB` and `ProjectC`. When I `tab`-complete `cd` to `cd Project` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it chooses `ProjectC`. I've found this is also the case with other similar cases; it defaults to the last in lexicographic order (but this may also be most recently changed/added).

Is this expected default behaviour for `cd`, or have I set something by accident here?

I'm running OSX 10.10.3, with bash 4.3.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't encounter that behavior. But I was able to reproduce it. Maybe you accidentially changed the option `cdspell`. See the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html):

> cdspell
>
> If set, minor errors in the spelling of a directory component in a cd command will be corrected. The errors checked for are transposed
>   characters, a missing character, and a character too many. If a
>   correction is found, the corrected path is printed, and the command
>   proceeds. This option is only used by interactive shells.

I tried it and it always corrects the path in the argument given to `cd`. If there are multiple possibilities like in your folder with `ProjectA`, `ProjectB` and `ProjectC`, it defaults to the one that is the last in the directory order. You can check that by `ls -U`. See the example:

```
user@host:~$ ls -Ul
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 40 May 26 08:11 ProjectA
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 40 May 26 08:11 ProjectB
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 40 May 26 08:11 ProjectC
user@host:~$ cd Project<tab><tab>
ProjectA/ ProjectB/ ProjectC/
user@host:~$ cd Project
ProjectC
user@host:~/ProjectC$
```

To disable that behavior use:

```
shopt -u cdspell
```

Comment: Interesting, but why does it pick the one that is last in directory order? This does not appear to be documented.

Comment: I can't find a source for that. In the source code of bash there is a function called `spname` that does return the correctly spelled filename. It is inspired by `the code in "The UNIX * Programming Environment", Kernighan & Pike, Prentice-Hall 1984, pages 209 - 213.`

Comment: Sounds like a documentation bug. You should probably report it to bash. If you do, you could include a link to the bug in your answer.

Comment: @chaos Ah yes, I see I have `shopt -s cdspell` set in my `.bashrc` (I did a lot of copy-and-pasting making an osx/linux cross compatible `.bashrc` and should have paid more attention obviously). I actually like it, I just couldn't turn up a search finding why. Thanks!